# Products sort with pick products from every brand and list accordingly

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have got 10 products with different brands.
Brand1 contains 3 products.
Brand2 contains 4 products.
Brand3 contains 3 products.

Currently, I am getting output as per relevance sorting (given example below)

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'product1',
    'brand': 'brand3',
},{
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'product3',
    'brand': 'brand2',
},{
    'id': 13,
    'name': 'product3',
    'brand': 'brand1',
},{
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'product4',
    'brand': 'brand3',
},{
    'id': 5,
    'name': 'product5',
    'brand': 'brand2',
},{
    'id': 9,
    'name': 'product6',
    'brand': 'brand3',
},{
    'id': 17,
    'name': 'product7',
    'brand': 'brand2',
},{
    'id': 20,
    'name': 'product12',
    'brand': 'brand2',
},{
    'id': 23,
    'name': 'product15',
    'brand': 'brand1',
},{
    'id': 7,
    'name': 'product10',
    'brand': 'brand1',
}
```

Now, what I want is as per below.
Sort products as per pick 1 product from every brand and then next 1 product from every brand and so on (as per the below example). And yes one more important thing. **I also want to add pagination to this output.**

```
{
    'id': 13,
    'name': 'product3',
    'brand': 'brand1',
},{
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'product3',
    'brand': 'brand2',
},{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'product1',
    'brand': 'brand3',
},{
    'id': 23,
    'name': 'product15',
    'brand': 'brand1',
},{
    'id': 5,
    'name': 'product5',
    'brand': 'brand2',
},{
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'product4',
    'brand': 'brand3',
},{
    'id': 7,
    'name': 'product10',
    'brand': 'brand1',
},{
    'id': 17,
    'name': 'product7',
    'brand': 'brand2',
},{
    'id': 9,
    'name': 'product6',
    'brand': 'brand3',
},{
    'id': 20,
    'name': 'product12',
    'brand': 'brand2',
}
```

Comment: How much flexibility do you have in changing your mapping, why not add a third field that you can ingest during ingestion and sort based on that. I doubt what you'd want is possible with mapping you have, you may want to change. What is your sorting or rational behind wanting `any` product with brand1 and then `any` product with brand2 and then `any` product with brand3 and repeating the entire scenario. I mean would that be randomized? Would your results be consistent everytime user queries. If so then sorting order has to be established right.

Comment: It's ok for me. If it gives me any product from that brand. I want to sequence brands in a particular position. The product order is ok for me if it's in sequence or random order but it would give me the same output every time if I run same filter query because I want to add pagination on it so.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use TermAggregation on "brand", then apply another subAggregation on the first aggregation, and at this time, use bucket sort aggregation on the field you want. 
For more detailed info please checkout this doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html

Edit:
Assume this is what your data is like:[image]

And first we invoke termAggregation on the field "brand" because this field is what you want to categorize your data right? Then based on this aggregation, we invoke another sub-aggregation (top hits aggregation) on the first aggregation, to get the data you want in a more accurate granularity. So the es dsl should be like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "name": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "name": {
                  "id": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you get the return like 
[image]

For the convenience I just set size as 1 to give you a more general screenshot. And you get and modify the data you want from each buckets under different "brand". Whatever you want it as round-robin or some other order. 

And for the pagination, you can fetch data from es first and then do the pagination logic in your own code. SearchScroll would be a help if you have many records in your ES. Search a batch of records, do aggregations on them, and scroll to the next batch. However, after all, ES is more like search engine rather than a OLTP database. The support of pagination is a little bit limited implemented by es due to its basic design. So DON'T DO ANY DEEP PAGINATION BY ES! And be careful to use this aggregation methods if your data size is very large. Because aggregations are CPU-intensive tasks and may cause OOM and crash your es clusters if such methods are in abused usage.

Comment: can you please give me an example? and also I want to add pagination

Comment: It gives me an exact output as a simple aggregation. I want product output in a simple one JSON as shown in the question.

Comment: Since you have the aggregation, the rest of work like JSON object concats, assembly, I think , is a simple business logic to complete.